# Delay Google Maps API's network requests

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to delay any requests that Google Maps APIs make to the network until my own requests are complete. We have some users on slow connection and we are competing with the maps API for resources. Is there any way to delay this? Any way to manually tell maps API that it is now ok to update? Can we tell the API to only download data over certain connection types (e.g. wifi). I think the trigger now is that once I inflate a `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` it automatically starts requesting data. I suppose I could manualliy delay that inflation but I'd like a cleaner way.